How to work with string properties in full fidelity analytical store schema in CDC pipelines?
I have a CosmosDB account using MongoDB API and am trying to work with the change data capture output of this.
The problem I am seeing specifically is that full fidelity string properties appear to work differently than other full fidelity properties and it is not clear how to work with them and successfully access the values of these in transformations.
The TLDR is
As far as I can see the properties of full fidelity string type seem to end up with two child properties both named stringas - one that is empty/null and one that has the actual value. Is this analysis correct and how can I access the actual value?
Full Reproduction
In a newly created MongoDB collection I insert a single document
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "firstName" : "Thomas",
    "lastName" : "Andersen",
    "addresses" : [
        {
            "line1" : "100 Some Street",
            "line2" : "Unit 1",
            "city" : "Seattle",
            "state" : "WA",
            "zip" : 98012
        }
    ],
    "contactDetails" : [
        {
            "email" : "thomas@andersen.com"
        },
        {
            "phone" : "+1 555 555-5555",
            "extension" : 5555
        }
    ]
}

And then set up a CDC pipeline connecting to the analytical store in that collection using the option to supply a Query as below
SELECT _id.string AS _id,
       firstName.string AS firstName,
       lastName.string AS lastName,
       addresses.array AS addresses,
       contactDetails.array AS contactDetails
FROM c 

After importing the projection it returns the following (with a sampling of paths expanded). This is nearly as expected for full fidelity schema except for some reason the string properties are called stringas

I only want to send a subset of properties downstream and also want to simplify the schema and remove the full fidelity artefacts so I add a derived column transformation with a single column named addresses and following definition
map(addresses,     
        @(line1 = #item.object.line1.stringas,
            zip = #item.object.zip.int32    ))

With the intention being that each array element in the addresses element is replaced with a simpler element with just two properties (line1 and zip) containing the primitive values.
Finally I push the whole thing into a JSON sink

Result
{
  "_rid": "2Uo7APnUuK8BAAAAAAAAAA==",
  "_ts": 1731422138,
  "_id": "1",
  "firstName": "Thomas",
  "lastName": "Andersen",
  "addresses": [ { "zip": 98012 } ],
  "contactDetails": [
    {
      "object": {
        "email": { "string": "thomas@andersen.com" },
        "phone": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "object": {
        "email": {},
        "phone": { "string": "+1 555 555-5555" },
        "extension": { "int32": 5555 }
      }
    }
  ],
  "__usr_opType": 2
}

Problem
For the addresses element the mapping of zip worked as expected but the attempt to map line1 left no trace in the output!
As an aside I did also notice that the property name for the contactDetails elements did get automagically changed to string in the output despite showing as stringas in the schema.
When I look at the "Data Preview" in the source I think I can see why line1 may be missing ...
The line1 property seems to have two child "stringas" properties - one that is empty/null and one that has the actual value. It looks like my derived column transformation is using the first of these properties, how can I access the one with the actual value?


Did you tried to convert it back into array before the sink? is it giving any error or giving required string array?

What do you mean convert it back into an array? map already returns an array as far as I see and the documentation indicates - i.e. I am taking an array of one complex type and returning an array of a different complex type. But the line1 value of that type is unexpectedly empty

If I name that derived column addresses2 temporarily this is how it looks in the debug,
https://i.sstatic.net/JsrZWa2C.png so it is an array with a single element and has a property line1  that is empty and a property zip with  a value

I found one solution. (Though I'm not particularly happy with it)
I found that toString(#item.object.line1) returned {"string":"100 Some Street"}
So for my use case I can just use a regex to get the actual value out of that (and use unescape for the case that value contains sequences like  \") .
map(addresses,     
        @(line1 = unescape(regexExtract(toString(#item.object.line1), '\\A\\{\"string\":\"(.*)\"}\\z', 1), 'json') ,
            zip = #item.object.zip.int32    ))

With this in place the relevant part of the final JSON written to the sink is
  "addresses": [
    {
      "line1": "100 Some Street",
      "zip": 98014
    }
  ],

so is no longer missing the line1 property.
I'm still not sure exactly what is going on here.
One clue is probably that the imported projection creates the following schema. It looks like ADF doesn't support string as a property name in its complex datatypes and automatically changes this to stringas - I'm not sure if this is causing some mapping issue here.
{_rid} as string,
{_ts} as long,
{_id} as string,
firstName as string,
lastName as string,
addresses as (object as (line1 as (stringas as string), line2 as (stringas as string), city as (stringas as string), state as (stringas as string), zip as (int32 as integer)))[],
contactDetails as (object as (email as (stringas as string), phone as (stringas as string), extension as (int32 as integer)))[]

If I no longer project a schema then I no longer see the doubled up "stringas" in debug view but then it is not clear how to access these properties with complex datatypes successfully in subsequent transformations in the dataflow.
